# Clone field collection row value in form on add another item

Tags: ajax, entities

I am new to this community and I hope I will be clear in my support request.

I have a custom form that uses nested field collection items as follows:

```
>     form
>      form_field_a
>      form_field_b
>      form_field_collection_tenant (with unlimited values) - add another item
>        field_collection_user_details (with unlimited values)  - add another item
>          field_u1
>          field_u2 etc
>        field_collection_instance_details (with unlimited values)  - add another item
>          field_i1
>          field_i2 etc
```

I would like to add a functionality so that when "add another item" for field_collection_user_details is pressed it will do a custom callback and return field_collection_user_details with previous field values populated so I can manually update only one field value an leave the rest unchanged.

Or, have another button created with a custom ajax callback to clone previous field_collection_user_details filled on the first delta. (saves time for let's say a field collection with 10-20 fields that require only changing one or two field values)

I am updating my question:
I have custom content type created which is being altered via hook_form_alter. begining of code pasted bellow: (is very long so I will just paste in until the relevant part)

```
function instanceform_form_plex_demand_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'instanceform') . '/css/instanceform.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'type' => 'file'));
$delta_i = 0;
$max_delta_i = $form['field_orig_tn']['und']['#max_delta'];
// we don't want to see additional settings block
$form['additional_settings']['#access'] = false;
$form['field_orig_tn']['und']['add_more']['#value'] = t('+');
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['style'] = '-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 50px!important; height: 24px!important; background-color: #E60000; border: 1px solid #fff; line-height: 20px; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; color: #fff!important;';
while ($delta_i <= $max_delta_i) {
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $delta_j = 0;
    $delta_k = 0;
    $max_delta_j = $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ic']['und']['#max_delta'];
    $max_delta_k = $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und']['#max_delta'];
    // add custom class to select tags for tenant
    $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_parent_nodes']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_en']['und']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-custom-select-tenant';
    $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ac']['und']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-custom-select-tenant';
    $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_lc']['und']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-custom-select-tenant';
    // add custom class to input tag for tenant
    $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_sn']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-custom-input-tenant';
    $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_sn']['und'][0]['value']['#size'] = NULL;
    while ($delta_k <= $max_delta_k) {
        // add custom class to select tags for user
        $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_actions']['und']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-custom-select-user';
        $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_permission']['und']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-custom-select-user';
        // add custom class to input tag for user
        $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_email']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'field-custom-input-user';
        // hide the parent node field as we are not using it within the Plex demand form
        $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_parent_nodes']['#access'] = FALSE;
        $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und']['add_more']['#value'] = t('+');

        $delta_k++;
    }
    while ($delta_j <= $max_delta_j) {
        ....
```

What i would like to accomplish is to add another "add another item" (e.g.: $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und']['add_clone']) button that will clone the values previously filled by the user (for $delta_k = 0) and return the form (field collection item form) with $delta_k=1 having fields with the same values as in $delta_k = 0.

EDIT2:
I have managed so far to add the second "add another item" button to the form however I cannot manage to set the default values in the ajax callback

In function instanceform_form_plex_demand_node_form_alter I have created the "add clone" button as follows:

```
 $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und']['#prefix'] = '<div id="field-clonefield-add-more-wrapper'. $delta_i . '">';
  $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und']['#suffix'] ='</div>';
  $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und']['add_clone']= array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add Clone'),
    '#submit' => array('0' => 'clone_field_add_more_submit'),
    '#name' => t('field_clonefield_add_clone'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array ( ),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'clone_field_add_more_js',
      'wrapper' => 'field-clonefield-add-more-wrapper'. $delta_i,
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
```

Then i have added the submit and callback functions:

```
function clone_field_add_more_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $button = $form_state['triggering_element'];
  // Go one level up in the form, to the widgets container.
  $element = drupal_array_get_nested_value($form, array_slice($button['#array_parents'], 0, -1));
  $field_name = $element['#field_name'];
  $langcode = $element['#language'];
  $parents = $element['#field_parents'];

  // Increment the items count.
  $field_state = field_form_get_state($parents, $field_name, $langcode, $form_state);

  $field_state['items_count']++;
  field_form_set_state($parents, $field_name, $langcode, $form_state, $field_state);

 >>>>>I THINK HERE IS WHERE THE DEFAULT VALUES SHOULD BE MODIFIED<<<<<

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function clone_field_add_more_js($form, $form_state) {
  $button = $form_state['triggering_element'];

  // Go one level up in the form, to the widgets container.
  $element = drupal_array_get_nested_value($form, array_slice($button['#array_parents'], 0, -1));
  $field_name = $element['#field_name'];
  $langcode = $element['#language'];
  $parents = $element['#field_parents'];

  $field_state = field_form_get_state($parents, $field_name, $langcode, $form_state);

  $field = $field_state['field'];
  if ($field['cardinality'] != FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED) {
    return;
  }

  // Add a DIV around the delta receiving the Ajax effect.
  $delta = $element['#max_delta'];
  $element[$delta]['#prefix'] = '<div class="ajax-new-content">' . (isset($element[$delta]['#prefix']) ? $element[$delta]['#prefix'] : '');
  $element[$delta]['#suffix'] = (isset($element[$delta]['#suffix']) ? $element[$delta]['#suffix'] : '') . '</div>';

  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to achieve this. I will post the answer maybe someone will use id in the future.

It seems that it was quite simple.

i have created an ajax callback function:

```
function _user_ajax_check($form, $form_state) {
// load the user then     
$delta_tn  =$form['field_orig_tn']['und']['#max_delta'];
$delta_tn_ud = $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_tn]['field_org_tn_ud']['und']['#max_delta'];
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
return $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_tn]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_tn_ud]['field_org_tn_ud_email'];}
```

The call with value assign:

```
$form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_email']['und']['#prefix'] = '<div id="field-'. $delta_i .'-user-details-'. $delta_k . '-add-more-wrapper">';
        $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_email']['und']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
        $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_email']['#ajax'] = array(
          'callback' => '_user_ajax_check',
          'wrapper' => 'field-'. $delta_i .'-user-details-'. $delta_k . '-add-more-wrapper',
          'effect' => 'fade',
        );
        if (isset($form_state['values']['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_email']['und'][0]['value'])) {
            if((isset($form_state['values']['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_cp_pre']['und'][0]['value'])) &&
                ($form_state['values']['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_cp_pre']['und'][0]['value'] == 1)) {
                $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k+1]['field_org_tn_ud_email']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] =
                        $form_state['values']['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_email']['und'][0]['value'];
                $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k+1]['field_org_tn_ud_actions']['und']['#default_value'][0] = 
                    $form_state['values']['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_actions']['und'][0]['value'];
                $form['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k+1]['field_org_tn_ud_permission']['und']['#default_value'][0] = 
                    $form_state['values']['field_orig_tn']['und'][$delta_i]['field_org_tn_ud']['und'][$delta_k]['field_org_tn_ud_permission']['und'][0]['value'];               
            }
        }
```

Result:[image]